# AngularJS: Different callbacks on clicking okay on the confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive

I have not worked with AngularJS much, I have a question, there are multiple buttons which open the same confirmation dialog box, but based on clicking on which button, dialog box opened, I need to do something different for each buttons. How can we achieve this without using any anti-patterns. Currently I declare a method and change its definition before showing a dialog.

```js
$scope.onClickButton1 = function() {
  $scope.submitDialog = function() {
    //do something specific when submitting for button1
  }
  $scope.showDailog = true;
}

$scope.onClickButton2 = function() {
  $scope.submitDialog = function() {
    //do something specific when submitting for button2
  }
  $scope.showDailog = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: as per your requirements you can create only one method for each button in your controller and pass value through parameters into that method and do further stuffs according to that parameter value.

Comment: What is your opinion on what I am doing currently? I need to do some check specific to buttons before showing the dialog as well, that's why opted for this solution.

Comment: my opinion is to create one function for each button and pass value as parameters from html code and put your condition in that function according to that parameters value. hope you are getting me...

Comment: Yes Kushal, I get what you are saying, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<button ng-click="onBtn1Click(); openDailog();"> Btn1 </button>
<button ng-click="onBtn2Click(); openDailog();"> Btn2 </button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.onBtn1Click= function(){
   //do something on btn1 click;
}


$scope.onBtn2Click= function(){
   //do something on btn2 click;
}


$scope.openDailog= function(){
   $scoope.showDailog =true;
}
```